# A good strategy to convert hashtags to links in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, hyperlink

I am working on an Angular project that gets from the backend (built with spring) various posts and show them. Every post has a text that can contain either a mention (@) or an hashtag(#). I need these two to be converted into hyperlinks.

Example:

this is an #example => `this is an <a href="something/example">#example</a>`

this is another @example =>
`this is another <a href="something_else/example">@example</a>`

One thing I tried was to use regex into the backend, modify the text with the various `<a>` tags necessary and then set that as the inner html into the angular application, but this is very, VERY unsafe.

I don't necessarely need the code implementation(that would be very useful tho), but I want some ideas on how to implement something like that into my application.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is to create a `pipe`.

That will be just a text transformation the only thing that you should change is that you will have to send them as `[innerHTML]`

**Linkify Pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'linkify'
})
export class LinkifyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    const regex = /(#\w+)|(@\w+)/gi;
    return value.replace(regex, match => {
      const link = `/${match.substring(1)}`;
      return `<a href="${link}">${match}</a>`;
    });
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<div innerHTML="{{ '@test' | linkify }}"></div>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This is actually a very good option. Still, my biggest concern is about the innerHTML. If the user sends in something like <img src/onerror=*malicious code*/> it is actually going to be rendered as an actual HTML component as innerHTML is used

Comment: I think it won't pass the DomSanitizer of Angular (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) so you don't have to be sacred of XSS attacks

Comment: I 've tried this now. DomSanitizer will still remove any (for example) <script> tags but will not touch any "harmless" tag (such as <a>, <img>, or <h1>)

Comment: I've found an half solution. Before applying the regex to find any mentions or tags, I apply another regex to delete any html tags contained in the text. I still wonder if it is possible to display any html as text instead of directly removing it